# Why isn't an array I create in a for loop accessible by my UICollectionView - fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, uicollectionview

I am trying to populate a UICollectionView with data from firebase but am receiving an out of range error when I try to pull my array[indexPath.item].

I can pull the data I'm looking for (red & blue fighters) then assign it into an array. But it looks like after the viewDidLoad closure, it clears the array - which is giving me an error when I then try to update my UICollectionView with those values.

Here are my variables before viewDidLoad:

```
var eventid : String!
var boutsIDArray : [String] = []
var redFightersArray: [String] = []
var blueFightersArray: [String] = []
```

Here is my for loop that pulls the data from firebase and assigns it into my arrays:

```
for i in 0..<self.boutsIDArray.count{
        let bid = self.boutsIDArray[i]
        ref.child("Bouts").child(eventid).child(bid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let redname = dictionary["red fighter"]
                let bluename = dictionary["blue fighter"]
                self.redFightersArray.append(redname as! String)
                self.blueFightersArray.append(bluename as! String)
                print(self.redFightersArray)
                print(self.blueFightersArray)
            }
        })}
```

And here is my collectionview where I receive the out of range error:

```
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return boutsIDArray.count
}



public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:ResultsCollectionViewCell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ResultsCollectionViewCell

    cell.redFighterLabel.text = redFightersArray[indexPath.item]
    cell.blueFighterLabel.text = blueFightersArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell

}
```

I'm a newbie so any advice or suggestions on how to link up my CollectionView with my arrays is welcomed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to access the `redFightersArray` and `blueFightersArray` before the network operation has completed.  Since the number of items in your collection view is set by the size of `boutsIDArray` you get an out of bounds exception.  Either drive your collection view from one of the fighter arrays or think more carefully about how your data should be structured.  Should you, perhaps, have one section per bout?

Comment: You should check the count of `redFightersArray`, `blueFightersArray` and `boutsIDArray`, I would assume that in your case they should be equals, else it would be the reason of crashing ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. When I print my redFightersArray and the blueFightersArray in my viewdidload they both come back with 2 items. So the boutsIDArray, redFightersArray and the blurFightersArray all return with the same count in the view did load....my boutsIDArray is being passed from another view controller so it seems to retain that but not the data on the other two arrays created by the forloop once it gets to the collection view

Comment: I have the number of sections and cell for item at entered at the very bottom of the view controller. Could that have anything to do with it?? Do I not have them in the right place?

Comment: why don't you use the model

Answer (score 0):

Change your collection view numberOfItemsInSection to depend either on redFightersArray or blueFightersArray

example:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return redFightersArray.count
}
```

And then reload your collection view when network operation is completed

example:

```
for i in 0..<self.boutsIDArray.count {
    let bid = self.boutsIDArray[i]
    ref.child("Bouts").child(eventid).child(bid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let redname = dictionary["red fighter"]
            let bluename = dictionary["blue fighter"]
            self.redFightersArray.append(redname as! String)
            self.blueFightersArray.append(bluename as! String)
            print(self.redFightersArray)
            print(self.blueFightersArray)

            yourCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

Above is simplest approach but it will reload your whole collection view whenever new item is added. So you may consider using [reloadItems(at:...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditems)

Comment: I can’t believe that’s what I was missing ‍♀️. Thank you so much!!